# How to add a custom action to the list items display form ribbon?

Tags: 2013, modal-dialog, custom-actions

How to add a custom action to the list items display form ribbon?

Onclick of this it should open a application page in modal popup.

Comment: That question is for list ribbon, but this question is regarding list item's display form ribbon... Is this both same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the Location attribute of custom action as `Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.DisplayForm"` Here is an example:

```
<CustomAction
Id="ExportVersionHistory.DisplayForm"
   RegistrationType="ContentType"
   RegistrationId="0x01"
   Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.DisplayForm"
   Rights="ViewListItems">
          <CommandUIExtension>
                 <CommandUIDefinitions>
                       <CommandUIDefinition
                        Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.Controls._children">
                              <Button
                               Id="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.Controls.ExportVersionHistory"
                               Alt="Export version history of the item to Microsoft Excel."
                               LabelText="Export Version History"
                               Image16by16="/_layouts/images/NY.ExportVersionHistory/Excel_Small.png"
                               Image32by32="/_layouts/images/NY.ExportVersionHistory/Excel_32.gif"
                               Command="ExportVersionHistory"
                               Sequence="99"
                               TemplateAlias="o1"
                               ToolTipTitle="Export Version History"
                               ToolTipDescription="Export version history of the item to Microsoft Excel."/>
                       </CommandUIDefinition>
                 </CommandUIDefinitions>
                 <CommandUIHandlers>
                       <CommandUIHandler
                        Command="ExportVersionHistory"
                        CommandAction="~site/_layouts/NY.ExportVersionHistory/ExportVersionHistory.aspx?List={ListId}&amp;ID={ItemId}"
                        EnabledScript="javascript:ExportVersionHistoryDisplayFormEnable();"/>
                 </CommandUIHandlers>
          </CommandUIExtension>
</CustomAction>
```

Even though this example does not open the page in modal popup, you can write the javascript code to do that. Source: http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2012/08/enabledisable-ribbon-button-in.html